# Can not use an arrow function with return void type hinting

Tags: php, arrow-functions, type-hinting, php-7.4

Using arrow functions in php 7.4 with return type hinting void results in a php fatal error. I think, that I am missing something. Can you help me.

Example 1:

```php
<?php

function returnvoid(): void {
    echo 'I am here, but do not return anything aka void';
}

$arrow_function = fn(): void => returnvoid();

$arrow_function();
```

results in

```sh
PHP Fatal error:  A void function must not return a value in [my_filesystem]/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.1/scratches/scratch_3.php on line 7
```

also Example 2:

```php
<?php

$f = fn(): void => 1;
```

throws the same Exception. I understand, that example 2 throws an exception because it is an implicit return. How is that for explicit calling a method/function with void return type hinting?

Why? I'd like to be specific in return types. Makes live easier with ide and debugging.

Is it not possible to return void in arrow functions? Am I missing something? Is this not documented?

Comment: Do not use arrow functions for void as they are meant to return something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) is meant to make the syntax more concise for single-expression closures.It can only have one expression, which is the `return`.

It's usually used in functions like `array_map` or `array_filter`, so using an arrow function with `void` type is not possible and also makes no sense (You already created the `returnvoid` function).

For your purpose, you can still use [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
function returnvoid(): void {
    echo 'I am here, but do not return anything aka void';
}

$anonymous_function = function() : void {
    returnvoid();
};

$anonymous_function();
```